# Having problems w/ Arraylist.toArray

Tags: java, arraylist

So, here are the 2 code snippets involved:

Declaration of arraylist in question:

```
static ArrayList<byte[]> photolist;
```

Array in question:

```
byte[] phofin = new byte[x];
```

Conversion(source of bug):

```
PhotoRetrieve.photolist.toArray(phofin);
```

The error message it's giving me says:

```
The method toArray(T[]) in the type ArrayList<byte[]> is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])
```

However, on this [java docs page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()):

There is an overload of .toarray that accepts an array as a parameter. I've tried lots of things to solve this issue, and have had no success, possibly because I'm new to Java and not the best @ troubleshooting. All responses are welcome. Thanks!

UPDATE:
In the declaration, when I try to change the type to byte, I get this error:

Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType

Comment: If you had an `ArrayList<String>`, what kind of array would you have to pass?

Comment: Because you are declaring your `ArrayList ` with type parameter `byte[]` but you are passing an array of type `byte`. You want to declare your array `ArrayList<byte>`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's completely wrong. You can't have primitive generics.

Comment: Sorry, sorry. `ArrayList<Byte>` and `Byte[]`, my mistake. I've been out of Javaland for a while. But I actually think I misinterpreted what OP wanted anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `ArrayList<byte[]>` is a list of `byte[]`. `T` is `byte[]`, therefore `toArray(T[])` is `toArray(byte[][])`. E.g. `byte[][] arrr = photolist.toArray(new byte[][0])`.

What you want to do is a bit more complex because you can't make lists of primitives, so you can't simply use `ArrayList<byte> ... photolist.toArray(phofin)`, you would need to use `ArrayList<Byte> ... photolist.toArray(new Byte[0])` and then iterate over the `Byte[]` to copy the values to `phofin`.